# Display required roles in Swagger / SwaggerUI

Tags: java, security, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

We're using @RolesAllowed annotations in our Jersey app to limit users access to certain parts of the API. How do we display this information in SwaggerUI?

So far I've annotated methods with @ApiOperation to display in/out parameters and attempted to use @Authorization/@AuthorizationScope but I've only managed to display it for oauth2 that we don't use. The closest thing to out case is ApiKeyAuthDefinition but it doesn't show up in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the framework you are using to generate your Swagger, but in the tooling that I use you have to specify it in the ["securityDefinitions" root node](http://swagger.io/specification/#securityDefinitionsObject) in the document and then reference that definition for each method that uses it.

Snippet from my Swagger 2.0 JSON:

```
"securityDefinitions":{  
      "dapiOAuth2":{  
         "type":"oauth2",
         "description":"OAuth2 security protocol used by this API.  Only one of the scopes that are listed for an endpoint are required to make the request.",
         "flow":"application",
         "authorizationUrl":"https://login.roguecommerce.com/Login",
         "tokenUrl":"https://login.roguecommerce.com/sso/oAuth2/token",
         "scopes":{  
            "RegisteredUser":"Assigned to users of an application if they are registered.",
            "Admin":"Assigned to the users of an application if they are an administrator. This role can only be granted by an existing administrator"
         }
      }
   }
```

This is how you reference this securityDefinition in the path:

```
"paths":{  
      "/v1/apis":{  
         "post":{  
            "tags":[  
               "Apis"
            ],
            "operationId":"Apis_CreateApiFromSwagger",
            "consumes":[  
               "application/json",
               "text/json",
               "application/xml",
               "text/xml",
               "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ],
            "produces":[  
               "application/json",
               "text/json",
               "application/xml",
               "text/xml"
            ],
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "name":"api",
                  "in":"body",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{  
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/DynamicApis.Services.Rest.Entities.Api"
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "name":"authorization",
                  "in":"header",
                  "required":true,
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ],
            "responses":{  
               "200":{  
                  "description":"OK",
                  "schema":{  
                     "$ref":"#/definitions/DynamicApis.Services.Rest.Entities.ApiBase"
                  }
               }
            },
            "deprecated":false,
            "security":[  
               {  
                  "dapiOAuth2":[  
                     "admin"
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to add this. I guess I'll need to write some annotation processor to map my @RolesAllowed annotations to security scopes.

Comment: You bet.  I just edited my response to include how you reference that securityDefinition in a method as well.  The 2nd snippet tells Swagger UI what the possible values for the security definition provided are.  Good luck!